# Is it possible to pass plugin variables from a parentComponent to a child as props in vue-test-utils' shallowMount function

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm building a jest test environment for a component I've built in Vue. The component expects as a prop an object that is computed by a vue plugin on the parent of this component. (specifically the `$v` object that is computed by the vuelidate plugin)

My approach to testing has been to use the `parentComponent` and `propsData` property of the options argument of vue-test-utils' `shallowMount`, but I cannot figure out how to pass the variable from the parent to the props of the component.

TextField.spec.js:

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import FormField from '../../../../src/components/fields/FormField.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuelidate);
localVue.component('form-field', FormField);

parent = {
  data() {
    return {
      value: 4,
    };
  },
  //this property is consumed by Vuelidate, which creates an object on localVue
  validations: {
    value: {
      required,
    },
  },
};
wrapper = shallowMount(FormField, {
  localVue,
  parentComponent: parent,
  propsData:       {
    label:          'test label',
    validatorField: $v.value,
  },
});
```

TextField.vue

```html
<template>
  <label>
    {{label}}
    {{required? '*' : ''}}
  </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: String,
    validatorField: Object,
  },
  computed: {
    required() {
      return Object.keys(this.validatorField).includes('required');
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

The expected result of the above code is for the `FormField` component to receive the `validatorField` prop created from the parent, but $v is not defined in the context I'm calling it. I have also tried substituting `validatorField: $v.value` with `":validatorField": "$v.value"` and passing a function in as well, without any success. Is there any way to pass this prop correctly? maybe by retrieving a reference to the parentComponent?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that I am **not recommending** to test more than one component in one test case (and I **would recommend** you to mock $v value directly without parent, because you should to test one unit in one test file, FormField in your case, and you do not want to worries how a parent component is working, not in this case, just test FormField and TextField one by one)

Whatever, I have some ideas why this is not working:

1. try to import real parent component like in this [example](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#parentcomponent)
2. try to debug and get to parent access `expect(wrapper.vm.$parent.$v.value).toBe('foo')`
3. you declare this

```js
localVue.component('form-field', FormField);
```

and after that

```js
shallowMount(FormField)
```

maybe there is happening something confusing

That`s all, sorry I have no clear solution, but maybe something will helps you (still recommend test components separately)